# Writing common properties to a class file in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, combobox

I have properties `CaretIndex` and `InputValue` im my `ViewModel` which are used for `Highlighting ComboBox Items which matches the text in PART_EditableTextBox of ComboBox`.
So, I want them to be in a seperate file. So, I don't have to type them in each and every time I declare a new View. But problem here is that these `CaretIndex` and `InputValue` properties's setter part depends on another Class's another property named `IsHighlighted` and the class may change for each new collection of data.

I have a ViewModel as follows:

```
public class GroupsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GroupsViewModel()
    {
        using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
        {
            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                                             select new GroupAndCorrespondingEffect
                                                        {
                                                            GroupName = g.Name,
                                                            CorrespondingEffect = g.Type_Effect.Name
                                                        }
                                            ).ToList();

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Add
                                            (
                                                new GroupAndCorrespondingEffect
                                                        {
                                                            GroupName = " Primary",
                                                            CorrespondingEffect = ""
                                                        }
                                            );

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.OrderBy(g => g.GroupName).ToList();

            Items = (from e in db.Type_Effect
                     select e.Name).ToList();
        }
    }

    public static GroupsViewModel CurrentInstance { get { return Instance; } }

    private List<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
    public List<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");
        }
    }

    private int _caretIndex;
    public int CaretIndex
    {
        get { return _caretIndex; }
        set
        {
            _caretIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CaretIndex");

            for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
            {

                string WordToSearch = InputValue;

                if (_caretIndex != 0 && _caretIndex > 0)
                {
                    WordToSearch = InputValue.Substring(0, _caretIndex);
                }

                if (WordToSearch != null)
                {
                    GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(WordToSearch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string _inputValue;
    public string InputValue
    {
        get { return _inputValue; }
        set
        {
            _inputValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");

            for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
            {

                string WordToSearch = _inputValue;

                if (_caretIndex != 0 && _caretIndex > 0 && _caretIndex < _inputValue.Length)
                {
                    WordToSearch = _inputValue.Substring(0, _caretIndex);
                }

                GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(WordToSearch);

            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The Helper Class that is used to get data in a different format (Get data in Two Columns for a comboBox.) is as below: (This class's `IsHighLighted` Property is referenced in the setter part of `CaretIndex` and `InputValue`.)

```
public class GroupAndCorrespondingEffect : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupName;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    private string _correspondingEffect;
    public string CorrespondingEffect
    {
        get
        {
            return _correspondingEffect;
        }
        set
        {
            _correspondingEffect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CorrespondingEffect");
        }
    }

    private bool _isHighlighted;
    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get
        {
            return _isHighlighted;
        }
        set
        {
            _isHighlighted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsHighlighted");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is move the common bits like `CaretIndex`, and `InputValue` to an *abstract base* class.

Refer to below Sample code to see what I am saying:

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _caretIndex;

    public int CaretIndex
    {
        get { return _caretIndex; }
        set
        {
            _caretIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CaretIndex");
            OnCaretIndexChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _inputValue;
    public string InputValue
    {
        get { return _inputValue; }
        set
        {
            _inputValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValue");
            OnInputValueChanged();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnCaretIndexChanged();

    protected abstract void OnInputValueChanged();
}
```

If you check the Setters for CaretIndex and InputValue, they are executing `OnCaretIndexChanged` and `OnInputValueChanged` abstract methods respectively - for which you will have implementation in the derived classes.

Now, your `GroupViewModel` will inherit from `ViewModelBase` and implement those two abstract methods.

```
public class GroupsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public GroupsViewModel()
    {
        using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
        {
            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                                             select new GroupAndCorrespondingEffect
                                             {
                                                 GroupName = g.Name,
                                                 CorrespondingEffect = g.Type_Effect.Name
                                             }
                                            ).ToList();

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Add
                                            (
                                                new GroupAndCorrespondingEffect
                                                {
                                                    GroupName = " Primary",
                                                    CorrespondingEffect = ""
                                                }
                                            );

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.OrderBy(g => g.GroupName).ToList();

            Items = (from e in db.Type_Effect
                     select e.Name).ToList();
        }
    }

    public static GroupsViewModel CurrentInstance { get { return Instance; } }

    private List<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
    public List<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCaretIndexChanged()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
        {
            string wordToSearch = InputValue;

            if (CaretIndex != 0 && CaretIndex > 0)
            {
                wordToSearch = InputValue.Substring(0, CaretIndex);
            }

            if (wordToSearch != null)
            {
                GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(wordToSearch);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInputValueChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");

        for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
        {

            string wordToSearch = InputValue;

            if (CaretIndex != 0 && CaretIndex > 0 && CaretIndex < InputValue.Length)
            {
                wordToSearch = InputValue.Substring(0, CaretIndex);
            }

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(wordToSearch);

        }
    }
}
```

You can follow similar approach if you want to *abstract* away your `IsHighlighted` property from class `GroupAndCorrespondingEffect`.

Hope this helps or gives you some ideas.

**UPDATE**

Added Class Diagram

[image]

Comment: Hello sir, nice to meet you again here. There will be a problem for me while following you. I have a 2 Column ComboBox called cbUnder in my view called Groups.xaml, So, to get it's 2 column values combined I have created class named GroupAndCorrespondingEffect. Now to get the Items Highlighted I declared IsHighlighted property in this class. Now if I create another abstract class for IsHighlighted property then it will work in this scenario. Consider another scenario where I have another ComboBox in my View which has just 1 column. continued in 2nd comment........

Comment: .......Continued .....There I will not have another class for it. Still I want to have IsHighlighted for that ComboBox as well. Now if I have another abstract class for IsHighlighted then my Viewmodel needs to inherit from that abstract class too. But upto my knowledge, a class cannot derive from multiple base classes. Now you will say I should create IsHighlighted property in ViewModelBase Class as well that you suggested in your answer. But problem there is that I have another view that does not have any comboBox. So, again there I don't need any IsHighlighted property.

Comment: @Khushi I mentioned you can do a similar thing if you want to abstract away IsHighlighed. However, from your comments, I see that's not what you want. I wouldn't ask you to move IsHighlighted to the ViewModelBase, as it doesn't belong there. IsHighlighted is only relevant in the Child ViewModels. Do you have many ViewModels with repeated code for IsHighlighed property too?

Comment: Yes I have approx. 60% of my
 ViewModels with repeated IsHilighted Property.

Comment: So, can you not have another base class (with IsHighlighted abstracted away) for all these Child View Models?

Comment: If I have another base class with IsHighlighted abstracted away then how can I Inherit my ViewModel from that class as my ViewModel already inherits ViewModelBase. I have read somewhere that a class cannot inherit from multiple base classes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, You will have CaretIndex and InputValue in one ViewModel and IsHighlighed in another Child ViewModels. If that is the case I don't see any problem in your main view model deriving from ViewModelBase and all the Child ViewModels with IsHighlighted can derive from their own ViewModel. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, you are slightly misunderstanding me. I have CaretIndex and InputValue in my MainViewModel which derives from ViewModelIBase. I have IsHilighted property in my MainViewModel as well as in my ChildViewModel.

Comment: Added class diagram with thoughts. See if that suits you.

Comment: Thanks, that is a perfect diagram.